# Is there any way to find the list of Oracle DBs installed on a UNIX server?

Tags: database, oracle, unix, sunos

I know there are Oracle DBs installed on my UNIX server. Is there any way to get those DB names? I'm using Sun OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try `ps -ef | grep -i pmon`. Each running `pmon` process would be for one DB and base on the `pmon` name your database would be `ora_pmon_<db sid>`. There could be additional DBs that are not running currently but this would give you the active running database on a Sun box. Also check the `/var/opt/oracle/oratab` as mention above for the listing of the DBs if the DB admin is keeping the DB properly listed in `oratab`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat /etc/oratab|grep -v "^#"|grep -v "N$"|cut -f1 -d: -s
```

Comment: I cant find `/etc/oratab`. Error : `cat: cannot open /etc/oratab`

Comment: issue this command locate oratab and then replace /etc/oratab with the location of oratab